# Puppet(-master) 3.1 after wheezy upgrade

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Today I've updated a Puppet client and a Puppet master to Wheezy.

For some reason, Puppet client was updated to version 3.1 but the master stayed at 2.7. So I've installed the latest stable version for the master directly from Puppetlabs, and both are 3.1 now.

```
root@efikamx-5fb019 ~ # puppet --version
3.1.1
botmaster /etc/puppet # puppet --version
3.1.1
```

However, I've noticed it started to spawn errors and fails afterwards:

```
root@efikamx-5fb019 ~ # puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for efikamx-5fb019.botnet.corp.yeri.be
Info: Applying configuration version '1367772083'
Notice: /Stage[essential]/Repository/Apt::Key[repository@yeri.be.gpg.key]/Exec[apt-key present repository@yeri.be.gpg.key]/returns: executed successfully
Error: /Stage[essential]/Repository/File[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list]: Could not evaluate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet.corp.yeri.be/files/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list
```

This is my auth.conf: http://pastebin.com/GGCyck95

This is my fileserver.conf: http://pastebin.com/XeeTX2a5

And this is a snippet from site.pp:

```
    file { '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list' :
        owner       => 'root',
        group       => 'root',
        mode        => '0644',
        source      => 'puppet://puppet.corp.yeri.be/files/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatturtle.list',
        notify      => Exec['update'],
    }
```

What am I missing to grant access to the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was the modify fileserver.conf, and set:

```
allow *
```

instead of

```
allow fqdn
allow_ip ip
```

Like this:

```
[files]
  path /srv/puppet
  allow *
#  allow *.botnet.corp.yeri.be
#  allow_ip 172.27.0.0/18

[plugins]
  allow *
#  allow *.botnet.corp.yeri.be
#  allow_ip 172.27.0.0/18
```